# Stripe customer portal error: Cannot read property 'sessions' of undefined

Tags: firebase, stripe-payments

I have successfully used Stripe to call a checkout session so that a user can subscribe to a new subscription but when I try to add code so that the same user can then maintain the subscription I get the following error in my firebase function:

```
maintainStripeCheckout
Unhandled error TypeError: Cannot read property 'sessions' of undefined at /workspace/lib/services/stripe/subscriptions.js:40:56 at func (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:336:32) at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

Can anyone explain why I can enter the subscription in the first place but then cannot maintain it?

My code:
index.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Stripe Checkout Sample</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="card">
            <h2>Stripe Payments Testing</h1>
            <button id="checkout-button">Checkout</button>
            <p></p>
            <button id="maintain-sub-button">Maintain Subscription</button>
        </div>
        
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.5/firebase-app.js"></script>
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.5/firebase-functions.js"></script>
        <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
        <script src="./scripts.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

scripts.js:

```
// Your web app's Firebase configuration
  // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaxxxxxxxxxxY",
    authDomain: "xxxxxxxxxx.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "xxxxxxx-framework-dev",
    storageBucket: "xxxxxxxxxxxx-framework-dev.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "xxxxx6479",
    appId: "xxxxxxxx7f88ea8a",
    measurementId: "xxxxxxRNG"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

  const checkoutButton = document.getElementById('checkout-button')
  const maintainSubButton = document.getElementById('maintain-sub-button')
  const createStripeCheckout = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('createStripeCheckout')
  const maintainStripeCheckout = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('maintainStripeCheckout')
  const stripe = Stripe('pk_test_koZ19rxxxxxxxxxxxx')

  checkoutButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
      console.log('Clicked Add Subscription Button...')
      createStripeCheckout({
        priceId: "price_1Iw7lCHx6drz9dmyercIcXEx",
        userId: "cus_JfbyXEfgxxxx",
        email: "test@e.studio",
      })
      .then(response => {
          console.log("sessionId",response.data.id)
          const sessionId = response.data.id
          stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId: sessionId})
      })
  })

  maintainSubButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
console.log('Clicked Maintain Subscription Button...')
maintainStripeCheckout({
  userId: "cus_xxxxxxxxxFPJ",
})
.then(response => {
  console.log("response: ",response);
  console.log("response url: ",response.url);
  const portalSessionId = response;
  stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId: portalSessionId})
})
```

})

and the firebase function:

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import {stripe, SUCCESS_URL, CANCEL_URL} from "../../config";
// const admin = require("firebase-admin");
import {getUser} from "../firebase/firestore";

export const createStripeCheckout = functions.https.onCall( async ( data, context ) => {
    // TODO: Do some checks to make sure the subscription and customer email have been
    // passed in correctly...

    const userId = data.userId;
    const priceId = data.priceId;
    const customerEmail = data.email;
    const user = await getUser(userId);
    console.log("users: ", user);

    console.log("PriceId: ", priceId);
    const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
        payment_method_types: ["card"],
        mode: "subscription",
        success_url: SUCCESS_URL,
        cancel_url: CANCEL_URL,
        // pass in the users email so that the subscription links up with the logged in user.
        customer_email: customerEmail,
        line_items: [
            {
                price: priceId,
                // For metered billing, do not pass quantity
                quantity: 1,
            },
        ],
    });
    return {
        id: session.id,
    };
});

export const maintainStripeCheckout = functions.https.onCall( async ( data, context ) => {
    const userId = data.userId;
    console.log("userId: ", userId);

    const session = await stripe.bilingPortal.sessions.create({
        customer: userId,
        return_url: "https://example.com/success.html",
    });
    console.log("PortalSession: ", session);
    return (session);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You've misspelled billing.

```
await stripe.billingPortal.sessions.create({
  customer: userId,
  return_url: "https://example.com/success.html",
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I have got past that problem now!